# RoR multi nesting with polymorphic associations + devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I have polymorphic associations with different models that I want to save upon submitting the registration form using devise. i.e:
User 
Company + ContactInfo
Employee + ContactInfo

I understand that nesting forms is not recommended but What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_one :contact_info, as: :contactable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_info
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_one :contact_info, as: :contactable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_info
end

class ContactInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

migrations:

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :contact_info, index: true
      t.string :website
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :companies, :contact_infos
  end
end

class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :employees do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.references :company, index: true
      t.references :contact_info, index: true
      t.string :job_title
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :employees, :contact_infos
  end
end

class CreateContactInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contact_infos do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone
      t.string :mobile
      t.string :contactable_type
      t.integer :contactable_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

registration controller:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:name, :email, :password, company_attributes: [ :id, :name, :website, :company_type, :number_of_employees, contact_info_attributes: [ :id, :email, :phone, :mobile]])
  end
```

devise's new registration:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag 'plan', params[:plan] %>

    <% resource.build_company %>
    <%= f.fields_for :company do |f| %>
      <%= render "companies/fields", f: f %>
    <% end %>

    <% resource.company.build_contact_info %>
    <%= f.fields_for :contact_info do |f| %>
      <%= render "contact_infos/fields", f: f %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
     <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
<% end %>
```

Console:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Nb6Na8P93s1dYvlDIQuiG11IoDeSzSylH4BCN8Tm7ipxCsbsdiWjDx5tJpijwldkjK4pPfjuwROnEvybYS7UIQ==", "plan"=>"free", "user"=>{"company_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Company Name", "website"=>"company website", "company_type"=>"company type", "number_of_employees"=>"121"}, "contact_info"=>{"email"=>"company@email.com", "phone"=>"1234", "mobile"=>"1234"}, "name"=>"user_name", "email"=>"user_email@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: contact_info
```

only User and company params are saving well. I was trying to get the devise_parameter_sanitizer to work with nesting contact_info in company first without trying the same with employee just yet, any idea what I'm doing wrong or any tips if im on the right track?

Thanks!

Update:

However contact_info params are permitted if I nest the contact_info form fields within the company form fields like so:

```
<% resource.build_company %>
<%= f.fields_for :company do |f| %>
  <%= render "companies/fields", f: f %>
  <% resource.company.build_contact_info %>
  <%= f.fields_for :contact_info do |cf| %>
    <%= render "contact_infos/fields", f: cf %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

the question is, is that good practice?

Comment: can you expand on "are saving well" (or really, what's not happening well) what exactly do you observe happening that is not working? Do you get an error? Can you show us the relevant logs for an attempt to save? (sometimes it's a permit/require issue and the logs will tell you what's not permitted. sometimes you can see that params are coming through as not what you'd expect)

Comment: @TarynEast Yes you're absolutely right, my bad. I've added the params from console to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is I don't have ```accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_info``` within the user model, which ofcourse wouldn't work as we have no relationship between them.

Comment: Yes, you've got the form set up as directly putting the contact info into the user, but you need the contact info to go into the company first (for example). perhaps you need a `fields_for :company` and inside that put your `fields_for :contact_info` ?

Comment: ok, I've added a plausible solution - looks like your nested contact-info isn't actually nested inside the company, when it should be... try this and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

This is a *guess* - but your contact_info for the company isn't nested inside the company section. Try something like this (note, not tested, probably buggy)

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<%= hidden_field_tag 'plan', params[:plan] %>

<% resource.build_company %>
<%= f.fields_for :company do |f| %>
  <%= render "companies/fields", f: f %>

  <%# this is now nested inside the company-fields %>
  <% resource.company.build_contact_info %>
  <%= f.fields_for :contact_info do |f| %>
    <%= render "contact_infos/fields", f: f %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
 <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
```